# Google SearchConsole can't see my sitemap

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have created an xml sitemap.
I have used Google SearchConsole to send it in, but the SearchConsole status says it can not be fetched.
I cannot see why. Anyone who can spot the error, or have some kind of method or work-around for letting Google find my sitemap? I have even added the sitemap path to my robots file. And the same day I did the exact same thing on another new website I'm working on, and it worked without any problems, so I can't understand what's wrong with this sitemap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.ortocare.dk/</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-02-05</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.ortocare.dk/behandlinger/prf.php</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-02-05</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.ortocare.dk/ydelser/speciallaegeerklaering.php</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-02-05</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.ortocare.dk/ydelser/funktionsattest.php</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-02-05</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.ortocare.dk/ydelser/second-opinion.php</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-02-05</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.ortocare.dk/prisliste.php</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-02-05</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.ortocare.dk/om-klinikken.php</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-02-05</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.ortocare.dk/kontakt.php</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-02-05</lastmod>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

A httpstatus checker returns 200 OK and Content-Type Application/XML. And both sitemap.xml and robots.txt checks out fine in some online tests.

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: https://www.ortocare.dk/sitemap.xml
Disallow: /robots.txt$
Disallow: /login
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell without having access to the sitemap file itself and some additional background like the contents of your robots.txt file. Have you tried an HTTP header checker to see what type of response it's sending? Can you post your robots.txt contents here, and have you tried using Google's robots.txt tester? https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

Comment: I posted a link to the sitemap, but apparently this is not allowed (it was edited away). I will see if I can edit my post to include sitemap content and robots.txt content in anonymized form.

Comment: It didn't work out well when I tried to post the content. Don't know how to show the content then, without link to the actual file, whch apparently is not allowed. I think I will ask some Google help directly instead, sorry.

Comment: You can paste the file's contents into the question, then select/highlight all of the code, and press the {} code button which will format it to appear in a gray box.

Comment: Checked and pasted - thanks WebElaine. I still can't find the error, except there might be a bug in the new Google SearchConsole?

Comment: Your XML Sitemap is not in proper XML format http://ortocare.dk/sitemap.xml so first fix that. Once fixed, submit it again in Google Search Console. (I presume that you have verified your property successfully in Google Search Console and there aren't multiple versions in search Console such had http:// https:// www and non www)

Comment: I think the sitemap is proper XML format @BhargavJoshi so if you could provide a line number or another indication of what you think is wrong with it, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Your robots.txt lists the sitemap at:

http://www.example.dk/sitemap.xml

However, your site seems to be secure, and your sitemap actually redirects to:

https://www.example.dk/sitemap.xml

(I'm preemptively replacing your actual URL with a stand-in, to follow the rules.)

If you're submitting the http version, that could be an issue. Try submitting the https URL in GSC. Also, make sure you register both versions in GSC, and set the secure one as canonical / main version. Finally, update all the URL's in your sitemap to the secure versions, to avoid getting the non-secure ones into the index.

Separately, feel free to delete the following line from your robots.txt:

```
Allow: /
```

as it is redundant; you've disallowed two pages, everything else is allowed by default.

Comment: Good point about the Allow directive. I have now removed it.  
And yesterday I changed the whole thing from http to https, so I have now edited the code in my original question.
Every suggestion here, I have carried out in GSC, but still status "Can't fetch".
Maybe I just need to be patient (not one of my core competencies) and try again in a few weeks. :-(

Comment: @niels Interesting. Okay, try using GSC's Fetch As Google feature on the sitemap URL itself, sometimes that turns up the issue. Also, your sitemap URL returns a 304 response. That means redirection to a cached version of the requested resource is taking place. Try emptying all server side cache and then resubmit in GSC.

Answer (score 0):

Submit your sitemap in https:// version and it will be validated successfully. If you are using http:// then you have to fix your sitemap format which is currently wrong.

You can validate your sitemap here: `https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html`

If you want to fix the problem in http version, refer to this screenshot:

[image: Wrong Format - Sitemap]

Comment: Aah - content header. I checked that from the beginning, but it must have changed along the way. Maybe some editor I'm using...   
Thanks a bundle!

Comment: Okay great. The content header you used, currently passes when used https://

Comment: Funny how it shows one content-header when accessed using http and another when accessed using https, for the exact same xml file.  
https://example/sitemap.xml validates just fine.  
I have a property on GSC for https://example/  
I have sent in the sitemap using the validated url on that property on GSC, and still get "Couldn't fetch". Frustrating.

Comment: Use "Visual SEO Studio" to generate a sitemap and then upload it. This will solve your problems as you seem to have problem with manually creating a sitemap.

Comment: Usually I have no problem creating sitemaps. Actually I prepared two different websites on the same day, creating sitemap and robots using the same editor, added properties in GSC for both websites in the same way, sent in the sitemaps only a few minutes apart. For the first websites is worked perfectly (as usual), but for the second on, the one in question, Google will not fetch the sitemap.  was hoping someone had run into the same issue before, and had found a solution.

Comment: If your solution is different than what I suggested above, share it with the community.

Comment: I will, if I ever find a solution. By the way, I did create and upload a sitemap using Visual SEO Studio. It's pretty similar to the one I created manually. But it didn't make any difference - GSC still will not fetch it.   
Visual SEO Studio creates sitemaps including the priority tag, which Google does not currently consume (but other search engines might), so I will probably replace it with my manually created sitemap again some day, but I'll leave the new one in there for a few days, just for the fun of it.

Comment: I suggested Visual SEO Studio since you have a problem in creating sitemaps manually. Back to the basics: "Did you do a permanent 301 from your http to https?" That could be another reason.

Comment: Thanks for advice idk, but you seem to be set on the idea, that I have a problem in creating sitemaps manually, even though you don't know if the sitemap itself is the problem.After all, the exact same method, including 301 rewrite to https, is working fine on other websites I'm working on. To answer your question: GSC would not fetch the sitemap when I ran http. Some days later, I decided to switch to https, and now I do a permanent (301) rewrite to https. Then I sent in the correct sitemap url to the https property. Still would not fetch.

Comment: Was just an assumption, nothing personal. Weird why it is working for you like this. I have the same problem in Bing Webmaster instead. It doesn't fetch but works great on Google Search Console.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but the problem have (dis)solved itself. Today I decided to go back to my original 'homemade' sitemap, but I tried one thing: I removed all urls except the first one and only kept the loc tag. Then it worked! Then I gradually copy/pasted - first the lastmod tag, then more urls - from a backup copy of the original file, and it kept working. Now I got the full sitemap file - all copy/paste operations from the original - and GSC is happy about it. Weird. One thing though: I updated Visual Studio Code today. But then again; the SEO Studio file didn't work either yesterday.